# Facebook Score Update Publish_Action

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, action

I have the following code to update the score of the user:

```
FB.api("USERID>/scores", 'POST', {score: currentScore, access_token: "APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"},
 function(response){ 
  if (!response || response.error) 
    {console.error(response);} 
  else { console.log(response);}
 }
);
```

The same code was working fine in my previous application. But this time even when I am getting the response rate true then also its not updating score. I have also tried by posting the score through the direct link(as below) to cross check in case I have some problem with my code.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/scores?score=USER_SCORE&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The result I am getting is as under:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "user": {
            "name": "Harsh",
            "id": "xxxxx"
          },
         "score": 0,
         "application": {
           "name": "xxxxxxxx",
           "canvas_name": "xxxxxxxxx",
           "namespace": "xxxxxxxxxx",
           "id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
          }
      }
   ] 
}
```

as far as I know this is result of reading score. Can someone help me where I am wrong.

FYI:
1. I am passing APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
2. My app is registered as Game
3. I am taking publish_actions permission